# MVC sitemap menu and sub menu

Tags: asp.net, mvcsitemapprovider, asp.net-mvc-sitemap, sitemapnode

Where to set to make selected item in menu sidebar as active and the submenu not collapsed? I am using Mvc.SiteMap to write my menu and submenu and the Template I Use is BeyondAdmin - Responsive Admin App

Comment: can you show us what you've tried? or what is going wrong with your current code?

Comment: In Sidebar If I click a sub menu then the aside bar remain active and breadcrumbs shows the details

Comment: <mvcSiteMapNode  title="Approve Data" controller="PensionerApproval" clickable="false">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Pending" controller="PensionerApproval" action="PendingApprovalList" area="Payroll" description="" imageUrl="typcn typcn-location-outline"/>
      </mvcSiteMapNode>

Comment: On click the action named PendingApprovallist the page remain active and breadcrumb display the information

Comment: On opening the PendingApprovalList and if you want to open a link to access the page, Breadcrumbs clear information and aside bar collapse